# Hide sub directory in url

Tags: .htaccess

i want to hide my subdirectory in the url. Example: i want that instead of **www.domain.de/loop/contact** it should show **www.domain.de/contact**,without the **loop** directory in the url.

Is this possible to make it via htaccess ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your httpd.conf file path from /var/www/html to /var/www/html/loop/

This should change the landing for home where your index file is found.